# A formula that yields a particular graph shape

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I would like a formula for a function whose graph has the following properties:

1. $f(0) = 0$.
2. $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = y$.
3. The shape of the function is approximately the following:

   [image: http://i.imgur.com/oH876.png]
4. It should have an exponential or a logarithm in the formula.

Any function like this?

Comment: Well, yes: the function whose value at $x$ is the height of the graph you have is such a function.

Comment: I think what Arturo is hinting at is that in mathematical terminology, what you want is *formula*, not a *function*. @Arturo, there are clearer ways to make that point, don't you think?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Could you give any function expression? Thanks!

Comment: @Rahul: Actually, no, I did not mean that, because I was not aware that this is what the OP is trying to do. Hard enough to figure out what he means by what he writes.

Comment: @RahulNarain Yes, I need a formula.

Comment: @Arturo: Yes, I noticed that just after I commented. Thanks.

Comment: There are $\vert \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} \vert$ functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself.  How many of those do you think have cutesy formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y = 5 - 5 \exp(-\alpha x)$$ where $\alpha >0$ will do the job. You can control the rate of growth by playing around with $\alpha$.

Answer (score 4):

The graph of $y=5-5e^{-x}$ has the desired characteristics. More generally, if you want $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=a>0$, the function $f(x)=a-ae^{-x}$ works.

Answer (score -1):

Also your graph doesn't have anything shown for x<0, so presumably its equal to zero there?

i.e. Use a piecewise defined function:

f(x) = a-a*exp(-x) : for positive x and f(x)=0 for non-positive x.